# Python, Tkinter, SQlite3 after login successful redirecting the user to a new window

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite

I'm new within programming and I created the following source code to verify if the user logs in successfully. I want to redirect the user to a new window and get rid of the current window, after they input the correct credentials within the entries. Is it possible to use the top-level method for this?

```
def Is_Valid():

    UsernameValidity=UserName_Entry.get()        
    PasswordValidity=Password_Entry.get()
    cursor.execute('''SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = ?''', (UsernameValidity,))
    cursor.execute('''SELECT username FROM users WHERE password = ?''', (PasswordValidity,))
    LogInAttempt = cursor.fetchone()?
    print (Is_Valid) # Testing 
    if LogInAttempt:
        print (" One of the accounts have successfully logged in ")
        IsValidText.config(text=" You have logged in! ", fg="black", highlightthickness=1)
    else:?
        print (" One of the accounts inputted the wrong credentials! ")
        IsValidText.config(text=" Invalid username or Password! ", fg="black", highlightthickness=1)
```

Comment: Is your Is_Valid function valid? Does it work? If it doesn't, there's no point in continuing

Comment: Yeah, it was tested and it does work. However, I want that once the user inputs the correct credentials to be redirected to a new clean window as well as the current main home page being closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your program works perfectly to this point, you are more than welcome to use the `Toplevel` method. I will also include the `.after()` to give time to let the user see the message.

```
def NewPage():
    global NewRoot
    root.withdraw() # hide (close) the root/Tk window
    NewRoot = tk.Toplevel(root)
    # use the NewRoot as the root now

def Is_Valid():
    # same as before...
    if LogInAttempt:
        print (" One of the accounts have successfully logged in ")
        IsValidText.config(text=" You have logged in! ", fg="black", highlightthickness=1)
        root.after(2000, NewPage) # or whatever your Tk is called
        # redirect to the NewPage function after 2 seconds 
    else:
        print (" One of the accounts inputted the wrong credentials! ")
        IsValidText.config(text=" Invalid username or Password! ", fg="black", highlightthickness=1)
```

This will close the original window and pop up a new blank window. Note: `.after(ms, callback)` uses ms, so 2000ms = 2sec

And you probably want to get rid of the two random question marks after `cursor.fetchone()` and `else`.

Comment: I get the following error :



AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'toplevel'

Comment: Capital T in Toplevel

Comment: Yeah, I tried. I still get the same error : AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'Toplevel'

Comment: How did you import tkinter?

Comment: "
from tkinter import *
"
The program stays up and shows that the login was successful, but it closes itself automatically and gives you that error after the timestamp.

Comment: Since you imported that way, it's just `Toplevel()` not `tk.Toplevel()`. In my answer I assumed you did `import tkinter as tk` which is the recommended way

Comment: Thank you so much ! Solved by abccd. Respect.

Comment: Thanks, and have a great day:)